# Не устанавливается Python>3.10.6 в Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

Все репозитории выбраны, `sudo apt update` писал. Вывод команды `sudo apt upgrade python3`:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово         
Уже установлен пакет python3 самой новой версии (3.10.6-1~22.04).
Расчёт обновлений… Готово
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Я поклясться готов, что 3.10.6 — это не "python3 самой новой версии". :)

Comment: Версия пакета (3.10.X) фиксируется на момент выпуска версии Ubuntu (22). Увеличиваться она не будет. Всегда будет 3.10.X. X расти будет, остальное нет. Если вам нужен 3.11, добавьте неофициальный репозиторий: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install python3.11`.